# Change Select value using GWT Uniform.js

Tags: gwt, widget, uniform, gwtquery

I'm using uniform.js in my GWT app. I need to change the values of the select item diagrammatically. But, the widget seems does not get updated. I know this can be updated using

```
$.uniform.update();
```

But, how can I do it in GWT?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read and attempt any solution using https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI

Comment: Uniform.js is based out of Jquery. GWT has a port of jquery called GwtQuery. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I has the similar issue. I tried the below JSNI. It worked for me.

```
 $wnd.jQuery(".checker span").each(function(){
 if(!$wnd.jQuery(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").is(':checked'))
 {
 $wnd.jQuery(this).removeClass("checked"); 
 }
 });

 $wnd.jQuery(".selector span").each(function(){
 $wnd.jQuery(this).html($wnd.jQuery(this).parent().find(":selected").text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeh .You can contact with jquery from gwt by using  [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) .

Try using this

```
public static native void update() /*-{
  $wnd$.uniform.update();
}-*/;
```

or like

```
public static native void update() /*-{
     $wnd.jQuery.uniform.update();
    }-*/;
```

And call the static method update() in your `GWT` class

Comment: Have a look on this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366123/calling-jquery-function-from-gwt

Comment: I tried $wnd.jQuery.uniform.update(); and $wnd.jQuery.uniform.update("#id");
I didnt get any error, but my widget doesnt get updated